# PubChem Service doesn't support isomeric SMILES specifications?

Tags: bugs, chemistry, serviceexecute

**Update 04 Sept 2020:** The problem described below occurs in Mathematica 12.0.  It has been fixed in Mathematica 12.1, so that `ServiceExecute` returns the correct response.

Consider the molecule defined by the following [SMILES string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system):

```
example = "C(/C=C/Cl)Cl"
```

(the [slashes indicate cis/trans isomerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system#Stereochemistry)).  [Molecule](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Molecule.html)[] has no problem interpretting this correctly:

```
Molecule[example]
```

[image: returned Molecule]

And a manual call to PubChem via the [PUG-REST API](https://pubchemdocs.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug-rest) works fine too:

```
 URLBuild["https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/smiles/cids/txt",
  {"smiles" -> example}]  (* "24726" *)
```

*BUT* the [PubChem Service](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/PubChem.html) seems to fail on this input, giving an error about being unable to standardize the given structure:

```
ServiceExecute["PubChem", "CompoundCID", {"SMILES" -> example}]
```

[image: error from ServiceExecute]

It's definitely an error with handling the isomeric specification, because removing the slashes that define the isomer allows ServiceExecute[] to return successfully:

```
ServiceExecute["PubChem", "CompoundCID", {"SMILES" -> "C(C=CCl)Cl"}]
```

[image: returns {24883}]

(albeit, this is a different molecule, and hence the wrong answer)

Comment: For these types of SMILES strings you have to supply the SMILES string in POST instead of in the URL.  The code doesn't take that into account.

Comment: I see.  So to confirm: the PubChem service execute in Mathematica only works for the subset of PubChem calls that use GET? (and does not switch to POST behind the scenes when necessary?)

Comment: It does switch to POST but not for SMILES.  I guess the SMILES strings they used to test it were lacking in double-bond stereochemistry.  I will file a bug report for it

Comment: This same problem also extends to SMILES strings containing a triple bond ("#");  A minimum breaking example is acetylene "C#C" ; this might also be useful to include in future tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this bug has been pushed via paclet update to older versions of *Mathematica*:

```
In[6]:= $Version

Out[6]= "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

In[7]:= Normal@
 ServiceExecute["PubChem", "CompoundCID", {"SMILES" -> "C(/C=C/Cl)Cl"}]

Out[7]= <|"CompoundID" -> {24726}|>
```